# Sql Join Group by count

Tags: sql

This query written based on transaction table

```
SELECT Ecode,COUNT(*) AS recvd 
FROM Transaction_tbl 
WHERE Locid=5 AND dtime BETWEEN '5/1/2013 00:00:00' AND '6/10/2013 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY Ecode 
ORDER BY Ecode DESC
```

while executing this query i am getting out put like this

```
Ecode        recvd
E003           24
E001            2
```

I have One more table like Employee master ,there corresponding Employee name is save,,how i can join this table to Employee master table

I want to get out put lik this

```
Ecode Ename Recvd
E003   jas   24
E001   deepu  14
```

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
SELECT e.Ecode, e.Ename, q.recvd
  FROM Employee e JOIN
(
    SELECT Ecode,COUNT(*) Recvd 
      FROM Transaction_tbl 
     WHERE Locid = 5 
       AND dtime BETWEEN '5/1/2013 00:00:00' AND '6/10/2013 23:59:59' 
     GROUP BY Ecode 
) q ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode
 ORDER BY e.Ecode DESC
```

or just

```
SELECT e.Ecode, e.Ename, COUNT(*) Recvd 
  FROM Employee e JOIN Transaction_tbl t
    ON e.Ecode = t.Ecode
 WHERE Locid = 5 
   AND dtime BETWEEN '5/1/2013 00:00:00' AND '6/10/2013 23:59:59' 
 GROUP BY e.Ecode DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8865/1)** demo.

Comment: @user2432269 You're welcome :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Comment: In the first query, if you have transactions with `Ecode` not available in the `Employee` table, you could change the join to a `RIGHT JOIN`, and select `q.Ecode` instead of `e.Ecode` in the outer select.  This will make the code and count show up, even though a name is not available.

Comment: Great example! Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.Ecode,COUNT(a.*) AS recvd, b.name
FROM Transaction_tbl a
INNER JOIN employee_master b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.Locid=5 
AND a.dtime BETWEEN '5/1/2013 00:00:00' AND '6/10/2013 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY a.Ecode 
ORDER BY a.Ecode DESC
```

Simply change `ON a.id = b.id` with you actual columns name that have a relationship and table name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.Ecode, e.name, COUNT(*) AS recvd 
FROM Transaction_tbl 
JOIN Employee e ON e.Ecode = t.Ecode
WHERE Locid=5
AND dtime BETWEEN '5/1/2013 00:00:00' AND '6/10/2013 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY t.Ecode, e.name
ORDER BY Ecode DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a foriegn key in your EmployeeMaster Table or Transaction_tbl to do what you want, If you do This will just help

If the foreign key is in the EmployeeMaster

```
    SELECT t.Ecode,e.Ename,t.COUNT(*) AS recvd
    FROM Transaction_tbl as t
    INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster as e
    ON t.Ecode = e.Ecode
    WHERE t.Locid=5 AND dtime BETWEEN '5/1/2013 00:00:00' AND '6/10/2013 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY t.Ecode 
    ORDER BY t.Ecode DESC
```

If it is in Transaction_tbl

```
    SELECT t.Ecode,e.Ename,t.COUNT(*) AS recvd
    FROM Transaction_tbl as t
    INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster as e
    ON t.EmasterForeignKey = e.EmasterPrimaryKey
    WHERE t.Locid=5 AND dtime BETWEEN '5/1/2013 00:00:00' AND '6/10/2013 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY t.Ecode 
    ORDER BY t.Ecode DESC
```

I hope it helps